# Android Magento Cart not active using API

Tags: php, android, magento, ksoap2

Recently, I created empty new Cart in Android Magento using Magento api method "shoppingCartCreate" in SOAP v2. I also set Customer Information in cart and added product programatically in cart.When I try to get cart information using "shoppingCartInfo" method, it gives field is_active=0. How can i activate cart from android?

I want Cart id assign with customer when customer logged in into android application. so i tried to get cart id from customer in php by following code:

```
$storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())->getStoreIds();

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setSharedStoreIds($storeIds)->loadByCustomer($customer)->getId();
```

Code working fine and returning quote id(Cart id) only if it is activated means is_active=1 else returning nothing.

when i try to login from website,as i click on cart (whethere it is empty or not) ,cart of current logged customer is automatically activated.

[Why does the Magento cart.create function make the cart inactive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899832/why-does-the-magento-cart-create-function-make-the-cart-inactive)